# pointerTap listener fires 7 times on PIXI.Sprite clicked once inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gsap, pixi.js

In a React application I use PIXI library for rendering animation, stage is created by `@inlet/react-pixi`, `gsap` for tweening.

On the first run the app creates a clickable `sprite`, then adds an eventlistener "pointerTap" with a callback.

```js
useEffect(() => {
chestSprite.on('pointertap', callback);
})
```

Once chestSprite is clicked, callback fires 7 times instead of 1.
How to make it fires only once?

I think the reason is that React re-renders several times on init and adds another eventListener on each render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing an empty array to the `useEffect` function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  chestSprite.on('pointertap', callback);
}, []);
```

Related documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects